# Js conditional statement not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

My **if statement** doesn't appear to be working when checking for **nonnumberic** inputs on the weight variable, upon submitting. Why is this?

```
   submitBtn.onclick = function(){

    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
    var pound = weight * 2.20462;

    //Check that the value is a number
    if(isNan(weight)){
     alert("Please enter a number);
    }
   }
```

Here it is in [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ssosina/ghzav3jx/10/)

Comment: Did you mean `isNaN`? Check your JS console: it's your friend. Also, meh: you're relying on coercion, and checking for a number value after already multiplying.

Comment: When you encounter issues in the future, make sure you [check the JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- You attempt to call `.onclick` on `submitBtn`, which is undefined.
- You attempt to call `.isNan()` which should be `.isNaN()`
- You don't close the string passed to your `alert()` function:

```
//Define submitBtn
var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
submitBtn.onclick = function(){

    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
    var pound = weight * 2.20462;

    //Call isNaN()
    if(isNaN(weight)){

        //Close your string
        alert("Please enter a number");
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ghzav3jx/11/)

Answer (score 1):

You might should use `isNaN`

```
submitBtn.onclick = function(){

    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
    var pound = weight * 2.20462;

    //Check that the value is a number
    if(isNaN(weight)){
       alert("Please enter a number");
    }
}
```